# Can't exec qmake

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu

I'm using `Ubuntu v.14.04 LTS`

I had on my computer `qt 5.5` but I needed an other version. Then I tried to install `qt 5.7.1.`

After a few issues because I didn't delate `qt5.5` before installing the new one, I saw on a forum that I had to delate the file qt in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.`

I tried to reinstall `qt5.7.1` but the error message apears: qmake: could not exec `'usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake'` because the install is not creating any `qt5` file in `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Then I tried the command line : `sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake` but it says everything is already update.

I lauched the command sudo apt-get --reinstall install qt5-qmake, and then qmake has worked. 
But when i launch on my app i have the same issue than before: 
Project MESSAGE: Qt version 5.2.1 
Project ERROR: Unsupported Qt version, 5.5+ is required

every results correspond to a 5.2.1 version : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/29/4/1500551296-capture-du-2017-07-20-13-36-09.png

I have launch " sudo dpkg -i qt5-qmake_5.7.1+dfsg-2ubuntu4~1_amd64.deb" that i had downloaded. But it says i have dependencies problems in qt5-qmake:amd644 => 
in qtchooser (=> 55....) whereas mine is 39... 
and in libstdc++6 (>=4.9) whereas mine is 4.8.4...

Comment: You should never have to manually delete files contained in a package. You probably crippled it that way... I suggest you try to force a reinstallation of the base packages for that library. `apt` offers the `-f` switch for that.

Comment: You probably ended up having a mix of versions. Check and compare the version of _all_ qt5 related packages.

Comment: after a apt-cache policy qt5-qmake i get: installed : 5.2.1+dfsg-lubuntu14.3 and only that one. I don't understand how to get only the 5.7.1 version when i have deleted the 5.2, 5.5, and installed the 5.7.1 version And thx a lot for your replies i'm on that issue since this morning

Comment: To list the versions have a try like this: `sudo dpkg -l | grep -i qt5`

Comment: Then you did not install the higher version.

Comment: Could you please add the additional information you gave to the question itself? There is an `edit` link below it. _Use it._ Also tell us what Ubuntu version that is and what repositories you have configured.

Comment: Why do you manually download some package? And from where? Why don't you use your repositories?

Comment: I tried to download the good one package by my own because when i launch the command sudo apt-get --reinstall install qt5-qmake that install the version 5.2 and not 5.7. I downloaded it from https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/qt5-qmake

Comment: You cannot simply install a package meant for a completely different version of Ubuntu like that. It will break dependencies for obvious reasons. Either you configure a package repository meant for your system which offers the qt version you need, or you have to create the packages yourself.

Comment: if i understand you are saying i can't have qt-qmake version 5.7 because my ubuntu version is not the good one? If it's not that what shoud i do to uninstall qmake v5.2 and install qmake v5.7 where "sudo apt-get  install qt5-qmake" give me qmake v5.2

Comment: That is not what I said or wrote, no. I said you cannot simply install a package built for a different operating system version. Packages have dependencies they rely upon. An older Ubuntu version as you use has other preconditions like library versions than the one that package was built for. And actually you see the issue: the software management _refuses_ to install that package, which does make sense since you would not be able to use it anyway because of the broken dependencies.

Comment: So either you need to upgrade all packages it depends on, an endless task since that is a recursive tree you look at, it comes very close to upgrading your operating system. Or you need to create packages for your operating system, _if that is possible at all_. Either create them yourself or find a repository that offers such packages.